# Angular - install all required packages at once?

Tags: node.js, angular

I get a project from my friend it has many packages installed. As I'm an absolute beginner in Angular I want to know the command or any other way to install all the packages which are used in the application.

Thanks

Comment: You can use npm install command, but you have to install Node.js first. https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: I have node.js installed already. This command should not solve all the issues.
I'm still facing problems in some packages.
however, as I run ng serve or ng serve -o both throw this error


- /home/aheer/Documents/QuickAccesss/angular-challenge/empire-eng/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/api.js
- /home/aheer/Documents/QuickAccesss/angular-challenge/empire-eng/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/index.js

Comment: As @ierhalim said, npm install will install all the dependencies and dev-dependencies. It's a mandatory process to do before serving the application. After that any error related should be posted in your question. Please attach the error as verbose as you can.

Comment: Maybe your friend has some of the dependencies installed globally and thus not added in package.json. This might be the reason why npm install doesn't help.
Ask them if they hav any Angular dependencies installed globally and add them via "npm install dependencyXY"